# Are character passwords on my iPad needed?

Tags: password-management

I have a 20 character password on my iPad. I've been wondering, do I REALLY need it to be that long? Should I switch to a 6 or even 4 digit numeral password? Or should I just shorten my password? Keeping it the same is an option, but I want a change.

Comment: Hi Noah, and Welcome to Security.Se. The answer to your question is really a function of what your threat model looks like.  Without knowing what threats you are trying to defend against, any answer given would simply be a matter of opinion.